# why shell uses 0 as success?

Tags: shell, operating-system

In C and many other languages, 0 means false and 1 ( or non-zero )
means true. In the shell 0 for the status of a process means success
and non-zero means an error. Shell if statements essentially use 0
for true. Why did the writer of the first shell decide to use 0 for
true?

Comment: Probably because there's only one mode of success and many modes of failure.

Comment: In C, many functions (esp. common in windows / winapi) that return an error status also return "0 for success" and a number to indicate a particular error.

Comment: @user2864740 That's less `C` and more `Windows` and ancestors though.

Comment: Because read the exit code as: `error code`. `0`-mean no error. `>0` some error - depends on the code... e.g. grep `1` error: no match, `2` - no file, `0` - no error = success.

Comment: *"Shell if statements essentially use 0 for true.*" No, it is not a boolean result. Take `0` to mean `zero error`.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status

Comment: juanchopanza has the right answer, and the convention is older than C or Unix.  IBM's OS/360 and the DOS/360 and TOS/360 operating systems they cabbaged up when they couldn't ship OS/360 on time, before the Unix project got started at Bell Labs (for about the same reason...Multics was foundering at GE.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The OP asking about the

> Why did the writer of the first shell decide to use 0 for true?

**The short answer:**
Isn't possible to answer this question in this form,
because the first shell **has not** any exit status.

### EDIT

Because @John Kugelman asked for summarisation, this answer getting a bit long.

Nor the second, third and Nth shell hasn't anything that could be called "the exit status". For the approximative correct answer, need to go to deeper into the history.

The *shell* was invented
by "Louis Pouzin" as the "RUNCOM" tool, in
the MIT's Compatible Time-Sharing System
[read about CTSS](http://www.multicians.org/thvv/7094.html),
where is written:

> Louis Pouzin also invented RUNCOM for CTSS. This facility, the
> direct ancestor of the Unix shell script, allowed users to create
> a file-system file of commands to be executed, with parameter
> substitution. Louis also produced a design for the Multics shell,
> ancestor of the Unix shell.

Read also [this page](http://www.multicians.org/shell.html).

The "next level" was in the Multics, called as
the [Multics Command Language](http://www.multicians.org/mspm-bx-1-00.html):

> The command language interpreter, the Shell, is normally driven by
> the Listener.

> Its function is to listen for requests in the form of command lines
> typed in at the user console. In the above command language
> description, the listener reads in a line from the console, evaluates
> the line as a command, and re-calls itself to repeat the function.

**It hasn't anything that could be called "exit status".**
The programs calls the `terminate{file/process} procedure`,
what stops the program execution.

And this is one of the most important points.  Need **differentiate** between

- **the exit as system call**
  When you terminating a running (compiled) program, (for example, in "C" using the `exit(N)`) in the reality you call
  a *library function*, what makes the bridge to the underlying operating system and correctly terminates the program.
  This means the "exit(N)" (from the point of view of the exit function) is OS implementation-dependent.
  [See Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_(system_call))
- shell's exit status -
  The exit status of an executed command is the value returned by the `waitpid` system call or equivalent function.
  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status). The waitpid like functions usually returns the exit status from the previous point, but it is OS implementation-dependent. (ofc, now standardized by POSIX).

Back to the history:

After the Multics, the UNIX got developed. [From this page](http://www.in-ulm.de/%7Emascheck/bourne/#origins)
the `shell` as we know today has two predecessors:

- the **Thompson shell** (version 1 up to version 6) - if someone is interested, [here](http://v6shell.org) is maintained a runnable version for the v6.
- and the **Programmers Work Bench [PWB]** shell
- the first shell that we known today was the [Bourne shell V7](http://www.in-ulm.de/%7Emascheck/bourne/v7/)

If interested, read through the manuals - links are [here](http://www.in-ulm.de/%7Emascheck/bourne/#origins).

The first mentioning of the "exit code" is in the
[Manual of the PWB (aka Mashey) Shell](http://www.in-ulm.de/%7Emascheck/bourne/PWB/).
All shells "before" talks only about the:

> Termination Reporting

> If a command (not followed by "&") terminates abnormally,
> a  message is printed.    (All terminations other than exit
> and interrupt are considered abnormal.)

**So, the answer to the question is in the above lines,** - in line what is already said in the comments:

- Because read the exit code as an error code. 0-mean no error. >0 some error.
- Probably because there's only one mode of success and many modes of failure.

Nice citation from the [PWB shell manual](http://www.in-ulm.de/%7Emascheck/bourne/PWB/)

> $r      is the exit  status  code  of  the  preceding  command.
> ``0'' is the normal return    from **most** commands.

*Notice the: **most** word. :), e.g. it was not invented in "one moment" by someone, but it is evolved in time. And it very tightly depends on the implementation of the `exit` and `wait-like` calls in the underlaying OS.*

For example, the 1st version of UNIX know nothing about the `exit(N)` levels - it was a simple `exit()` and the `wait` didn't return a specific value - [from](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/man22.pdf) the [The first edition of the Unix Programmer's Manual, dated November 3, 1971](http://www.cs.bell-labs.com/who/dmr/1stEdman.html)

> **exit** is the normal means of terminating a process. All files are
> closed and the parent process is notified if it is executing a wait.

> **wait** causes its caller to delay until one of its child processes terminates. If any child has already died, return is immediate; if
> there are no children, return is immediate with the error bit set.

Also, [read here - really worth - The Evolution of the Unix Time-sharing System](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/hist.html) - about the evolution of the `fork`, `exec`, `exit` and `wait`...

The V7 standardized the exit status as:

> The value of a simple command is its
> exit status if it terminates normally or  200+status  if  it
> terminates     abnormally  (see  signal(2) for a list of status
> values).

also:

> **DIAGNOSTICS**
> Errors detected by the shell, such    as syntax errors cause
> the shell to return a non-zero exit status.  If the shell is
> being used    non interactively then  execution of the shell
> file is abandoned.   Otherwise, the shell returns the exit
> status of the last command    executed (see also exit).

Howg.. OMG... Someone could be so nice as to edit this post and correct my broken English and/or extend/correct the above...

And finally - sorry folks - totally of the topic - but can't resist adding the following [image](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/xenix.gif) from the history - not many current users know Microsoft-XENIX. ;)
[image]

Comment: Would be nice go get some feedback from the down voter how to improve this answer.

Comment: Steve Bourne gave the keynote talk at BSDCan 2015 and in it he mentioned about how he initially had to have the shell print the exit status of every command just before it prints the prompt again in order to get people to fix their programs to give a consistent exit status (i.e. to call exit(0) on success, or exit(1), etc. on failure) that could then be used reliably in conditional statements in scripts for branching or to detect errors from commands.

Answer (score 0):

In most processors, the processor status indicates if the last instruction produced a zero value. One can branch if zero (or nonzero) without explicitly comparing with zero (saving instruction cycles). If you make zero success, that gives multiple ways to return failure (and save instructions).

This is actually a very poor convention. The VMS operating system from the 70's remains more advanced then nearly every over system in use today. It had a centralized error system in which applications could add their own error messages and codes which would be integrated with system error codes. In the VMS system, odd values were success and even values were failures.

Let's say you had a function that opens a file. You could have one success code that says it opened an existing file and another that says it created a new file.