# Bash Weirdness: Exit Codes of Arithmetic Expressions in Relation to Conditionals. true/false vs. success/failure

Tags: bash, conditional-statements, arithmetic-expressions

According to the `bash` `man` page,

> `while list-1; do list-2; done`
> The while command continuously executes the list list-2 as long as the last command in the list, list-1, returns  an exit status of zero.

I'm trying to make sense of how bash is interpreting the exit codes of arithmetical expressions when they appear at the end of list-1.  I started with some experiments:

```
$ echo $((1))                                                                                                                                                                                                             
1                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
$ ((1)); echo $?                                                                                                                                                                                                          
0                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
$ echo $((! 1))
0                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
$ ((! 1)); echo $?  # Hm, what does this exit code mean?
1                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
$ while ((1)); do echo "yes"; break; done                                                                                     
yes 

# This could be responding to either the exit code of ((1))
# or to it's value, 1 meaning true
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
$ while ((! 1)); do echo "yes"; break; done                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
# This could be responding to either the exit code of ((! 1)), 
# or to it's value, 0 meaning false
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
$ while ! ((1)); do echo "yes"; break; done                                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
# this ! should change the exit code, not the value, 
# so it appear to be responding to the exit code
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
$ echo $((0))                                                                                                                                                                                                             
0                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
$ ((0)); echo $?  # Hm, what does this exit code mean?
1                      
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
$ echo $((! 0)))                                                                                                                                                                                                          
1                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
$ ((! 0)); echo $?                                                                                                                                                                                                        
0                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
$ while ((0)); do echo "yes"; break; done

# This could be responding to either the exit code of ((0)) 
# or to it's value, 0 meaning false
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
$ while ((! 0)); do echo "yes"; break; done                                                                                                                                                                               
yes                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
# This could be responding to either the exit code of ((! 0)) 
# or to it's value, 1 meaning true                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
$ while ! ((0)); do echo "yes"; break; done                                                                                                                                                                               
yes                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
# this ! should change the exit code, not the value, 
# so it appears to be responding to the exit code.
```

So, after fixing two errors (thanks @Barmar), there is a consistent interpretation based on the while loop looking at exit codes.  What remains obscure is why the exit code of `((0))` is failure, and the exit code of `((1))` is success.

I came across this while trying to capture exit codes of functions in the while condition for use when the loop breaks:

```
while <function>; do
    <stuff>
done

# I need the exit code of <function> here.
```

So, perhaps this way:

```
while <function>; ((! (RESULT=$?) )); do  # alternative ! (( RESULT=$? ))
    <stuff>
done
```

Comment: FYI: `while` with an immediate `break` is the same as `if`.

Comment: Thanks.  The `while` I'm actually running loops more than once, so this is simplified, but I supposed I could have used an `if` to distill it even further.

Comment: When I do `((! 1)); echo $?` I get `1`.

Comment: @Barmar Hm.  That one you are right about.  Let me see what that means ...

Comment: Relevant: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32250/why-does-a-0-let-a-return-exit-code-1/32251#32251

Comment: `((0))` is a conditional that evaluates `0` (`true`) and returns `1` correctly. `((! 0))` is a conditional that evaluates `1` (`false`) and returns `0` appropriately.

Comment: Does this answer your quesiton https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28705927/why-shell-uses-0-as-success https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68555944/logic-operator-evaluation-in-bash/68556053#68556053  ?

Comment: Thanks @KamilCuk , but that answer doesn't explain how true/false is coded in bash to relate to success/vailure.  The other answers here do explain that.

Comment: Hm, "is coded in bash" it's just like that, from https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#index-let `If the value of the expression is non-zero, the return status is 0; otherwise the return status is 1`, there's nothing more to explain. If you really are interested in "how is coded", then https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/f3a35a2d601a55f337f8ca02a541f8c033682247/builtins/let.def#L108 .

Comment: Ok, I see that now in the `man` page, but I don't see it at that stackoverflow answer that you linked.  Thanks for that.  It's right there, but I missed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What `bash` is doing is associating `((1))`, which evaluates to `1`, to "truth".  It then makes that consistent with exit codes by returning an exit code of success, `0`.  Similarly, it is associating `((0))`, which evaluates to `0`, to "false".  It them makes that consistent with exit codes by return the exit code of failure, `1`.

This may seem confusing, as after all both evaluations `((.))` are "successful", but this is a hack to bring the value of arithmetic expressions representing true/false in line with bash's exit codes of success/failure, and make conditional expressions like `if ...; then ...; fi`, `while ...; do ...; done`, etc, work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Anything that evaluates to zero is false, anything that does not is true.

It means you can do things like:

```
while :; do
    ((c++%5)) || ((val=RANDOM))
    echo "$val changes every 5 iterations"
    sleep 0.5
done
```

Negative numbers are not zero:

```
$ ((20-30)); echo $?
0
$ ((20-20)); echo $?
1
$ ((20-10)); echo $?
0
```

For `((! 0))`, the logical negation of 0 is 1, and `((1))` returns true (0). For `!((0))`, the return value false (1), is negated by the (non arithmetic) operator `!`, causing the return value of the arithmetic subshell to be true (0) instead of false.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out what happens with negative numbers.